# VSCode debugger freezes

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a C++ file in VSCode. The debugger works fine while it is in the `main()` function, but as soon as it enters a function, the debugger freezes and the control panel no longer works(except the stop button). In the left bar, it shows the loading icon next to "Local" variables, which loads perpetually.

I am on macOS 11.3.1, and VSCode Version: 1.58.2 (Universal).

Here are my files: `debug.cpp`

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<queue> 
#include<vector>
#include<map> 
#include<stack> 
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int longestConsecutive(vector<int>& nums) {

    unordered_map<int, bool> hash;
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        hash[nums[i]] = true;
    }

    int max_range = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<nums.size()-1; i++){
        if(hash[nums[i]]){
            hash[nums[i]] = false;
            int j = i-1;
            int leftRange = 0;
            while(hash[nums[j]] && j>=0){
                hash[nums[j]] = false;
                leftRange++;
                j--;
            }
            int k = i+1;
            int rightRange = 0;
            while(hash[nums[k]] && k<nums.size()){
                hash[nums[k]] = false;
                rightRange++;
                k++;
            }
            if(leftRange+rightRange+1 > max_range){
                max_range = leftRange+rightRange+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return max_range;

}

int main(){
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(100);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(200);
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(2);

    int ans = longestConsecutive(vec);

    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

`launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

A thing to note, when I change my `longestConsecutive` function in `debug.cpp`, and make it something entirely random like:

```
int temp;
temp = 100;
return temp;
```

then the debugger works fine. Is there something wrong with the code I wrote?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of your backwards range checks should be fixed, lest you introduce UB. Ex: `while(hash[nums[j]] && j>=0)` is backwards. It should be `while(j>=0 && hash[nums[j]])`.  Similar problem here: `while (hash[nums[k]] && k<nums.size())`. The latter expression should only be considered when the first expression is true, and the first expression should *always* verify the later expression can be evaluated without UB. This happens multiple times in your program. The compiler warnings about signed/unsigned usages concerning `size_t` vs `int` are also worthwhile to consider.

Comment: Unrelated: CodeLLDB is an outstanding debugging extension for MacOS using clang and lldb, and I strongly suggest it worth the look.

Comment: I'll give CodeLLDB a try, and I did not know that range checks should be done before any other ones. I'll fix them ASAP! :D

Comment: why do you need the `hash` variable to be a `map`?

Comment: @rioV8 Solving [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/) leetcode question. My logic is to map all the numbers in the given array as true, and then start iterating at the first index of the hashtable. I will check for every index `i`, if hash[i-1] exists or not. If it does, then I increment range counter by one, and set its mapped value to false because I have already considered it in the range. If not, then I repeat this process on the right side of `i`, and finally compare the current range to `max_range`. Can this question be solved in a better manner?

Comment: read my comment again. There is a more efficient data structure you can use instead of `map`

Comment: looking at your solution again I wonder if it will give you the correct answer. Have you done a paper and pencil try of the first example in the question. Have you read that `n` is unsorted.

Comment: @rioV8 Yep, my solution would run in O(N) time and space, it doesn't matter if the given input is sorted or not, since I am only working with the hash map. The above code will give the wrong answer, but it will work with some adjustments. My logic was correct, but my implementation was wrong. As far as my question is considered, I resorted to using XCode for debugging :P

Comment: By the way, what was your approach? I'd love to know more about it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I 've met this situation exactly before.
just change configurations [type] from "cppdbg" to "lldb" in launch.json solve this problem.
hope it helps you.

Comment: This solve it. The documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_type) causes so much confusion. On Macos, 'lldb' works and 'cppdbg' does not when using gdb.